# What debate took place between Shree Yajnavalkya Rushi and his Guru Shree Uddalaka during the King Janakas sacrifice?

Tags: yajur-veda, janaka, yajnavalkya

While reading about great **Rushi Shree Yajnavalkya** , I have came across a story about him [Read here](http://sivanandaonline.org/public_html/?cmd=displaysection&section_id=1379)

This is the short story -

> Once King Janaka of Videha wanted to know from which real
> **Brahmanishtha** (one who is well-versed in  the scriptures and
> established in **Brahma Jnana**. to receive Brahma Vidya.)  In order to
> find out who was the real Brahma-nishtha, Janaka performed a huge
> Bahu-dakshina   sacrifice to which all the Rishis from far and wide
> were invited. And he offered one thousand   cows with their calves,
> all their horns being decked with enormous gold. Then he proclaimed to
> the assembled ones, "Whosoever is the best Brahmana amongst you may
> drive these cows home".   None dared to get up and take away the cows
> as they were afraid of censure by the others. But  Yajnavalkya stood
> up and asked his disciple Samasravas to drive the cows home.
>
> The other Brahmanas got angry at this and said to one another, "How
> can he declare himself to  be the best among us?". Thereupon several
> Rishis challenged Yajnavalkya with many questions on  transcendental
> matters to all of which Yajnavalkya gave prompt reply. There was a
> great debate  in which **Yajnavalkya won over all the others**. Janaka was
> convinced that Yajnavalkya was the  best Brahma-nishtha and received
> Brahma Vidya from him thereafter.

Many Rushies asked so many questions to him about various subjects during this question answer session including "Asvala" -King Jankas priest ,
Rishi "Artabhaga" of the family of Jaratkaru , Rishi "Bhujyu" of the Lahya family ,Ushasti Chakrayana , Kahola Kaushitakeya. And **Gargi,(a female rushi) the daughter of
Vachaknu.** [Read here](http://www.searchforlight.org/Anubhuti/AnubhutiVol2no1/Nolini%20kant%20Gupta(p)parable,rishi%20yajnavalkya,1.htm)

> **Similarly, he also debated with another of his teachers, Uddalaka, thus overcoming him during this.** [Read Here](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Yajnavalkya)

**My question is -**

**What is the debate that was took place between Shree Yajnavalkya and his Guru (Teacher) Shree Uddalaka during  the King Janakas sacrifice.?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The debate of Yajnavalkya with Gargi and his teacher Uddalaka is in Brihadaranyaka Upanishad.

Here is  with Gargi:

> iii-vi-1: Then Gargi, the daughter of Vacaknu, asked him, ‘Yajnavalkya’,
>   she said, ‘if all this is pervaded by water, by what is water pervaded ?’
>   ‘By air, O Gargi’. ‘By what is air pervaded?’ ‘By the sky, O Gargi’. ‘By
>   what is the sky pervaded ?’ ‘By the world of the Gandharvas, O Gargi’.
>   ‘By what is the world of the Gandharvas pervaded ?’ ‘By the sun, O
>   Gargi.’ ‘By what is the sun pervaded ?’ ‘By the moon, O Gargi.’ ‘By
>   what is the moon pervaded ?’ ‘By the stars, O Gargi’. ‘By what are the
>   stars pervaded ?’ ‘By the world of the gods, O Gargi’. ‘By what is the
>   world of the gods pervaded ?’ ‘By the world of Indra, O Gargi’. By what
>   is the world of Indra pervaded?’ ‘By the world of Viraj, O Gargi’. ‘By
>   what is the world of Viraj pervaded?’ ‘ By the world of Hiranyagarbha,
>   O Gargi’. ‘By what is the world of Hiranyagarbha pervaded ?’ He said,
>   ‘Do not, O Gargi, push your inquiry too far, lest your head should fall
>   off. You are questioning about a deity that should not be reasoned
>   about. Do not, O Gargi, push your inquiry too far.’ Thereupon Gargi, the
>   daughter of Vacaknu, kept silent.

Then after this debate with Uddalaka starts as:

> III-vii-1: Then Uddalaka, the son of Aruna, asked him. ‘Yajnavalkya’,
>   said, ‘in Madra we lived in the house of Patanchala Kapya (descendant
>   of Kapi), studying the scriptures on sacrifices. His wife was possessed
>   by a Gandharva. We asked him who he was. He said, "Kabandha, the
>   son of Atharvan". He said to Patanchala Kapya and those who studied
>   the scriptures on sacrifices, "Kapya, do you know that Sutra by which
>   this life, the next life and all beings are held together ?" Patanchala
>   Kapya said, "I do not know it, sir". The Gandharva said to him and the
>   students, "Kapya, do you know that Internal Ruler who controls this and
>   the next life and all beings from within ?" Patanchala Kapya said, "I do
>   not know Him, sir". The Gandharva said to him and the students, "He
>   who knows that Sutra and that Internal Ruler as above indeed knows
>   Brahman, knows the worlds, knows the gods, knows the Vedas, knows
>   beings, knows the self, and knows everything". He explained it all to
>   them. I know it. If you, Yajnavalkya, do not know that Sutra and that
>   Internal Ruler, and still take away the cows that belong only to the
>   knowers of Brahman, your head shall fall off’. ‘I know, O Gautama, that
>   Sutra and that Internal Ruler’. ‘Any one can say, "I know, I know". Tell
>   us what you know.’ 
>  
>   III-vii-2: He said, ‘Vayu, O Gautama, is that Sutra. Through this Sutra or
>   Vayu this and the next life and all beings are held together. Therefore,
>   O Gautama, when a man dies, they say that his limbs have been
>   loosened, for they are held together, O Gautama, by the Sutra or
>   Vayu.’ ‘Quite so, Yajnavalkya. Now describe the Internal Ruler.’ 
>  
>   III-vii-3: He who inhabits the earth, but is within it, whom the earth
>   does not know, whose body is the earth, and who controls the earth from within, is the Internal Ruler, your own immortal self. 
>  
>   III-vii-4: He who inhabits water, but is within it, whom water does not
>   know, whose body is water, and who controls water from within, is the
>   Internal Ruler, your own immortal self. 
>  
>   III-vii-5: He who inhabits fire, but is within it, whom fire does not know,
>   whose body is fire, and who controls fire from within, is the Internal
>   Ruler, your own immortal self. 
>  
>   III-vii-6: He who inhabits the sky, but is within it, whom the sky does
>   not know, whose body is the sky, and who controls the sky from within,
>   is the Internal Ruler, your own immortal self. 
>  
>   III-vii-7: He who inhabits air, but is within it, whom air does not know,
>   whose body is air, and who controls air from within, is the Internal
>   Ruler, your own immortal self. 
>  
>   III-vii-8: He who inhabits heaven, but is within it, whom heaven does
>   not know, whose body is heaven, and who controls heaven from within,
>   is the Internal Ruler, your own immortal self. 
>  
>   III-vii-9: He who inhabits the sun, but is within it, whom the sun does
>   not know, whose body is the sun, and who controls the sun from within,
>   is the Internal Ruler, your own immortal self. 
>  
>   III-vii-10: He who inhabits the quarters, but is within it, whom the
>   quarters does not know, whose body is the quarters, and who controls
>   the quarters from within, is the Internal Ruler, your own immortal self. 
>  
>   III-vii-11: He who inhabits the moon and stars, but is within it, whom
>   the moon and stars does not know, whose body is the moon and stars,
>   and who controls the moon and stars from within, is the Internal Ruler,
>   your own immortal self. 
>  
>   III-vii-12: He who inhabits the ether, but is within it, whom the ether
>   does not know, whose body is the ether, and who controls the ether
>   from within, is the Internal Ruler, your own immortal self. 
>  
>   III-vii-13: He who inhabits darkness, but is within it, whom darkness
>   does not know, whose body is darkness, and who controls darkness
>   from within, is the Internal Ruler, your own immortal self.
>   III-vii-14: He who inhabits light, but is within it, whom light does not
>   know, whose body is light, and who controls light from within, is the
>   Internal Ruler, your own immortal self. This much with reference to the
>   gods. Now with reference to the beings. 
>  
>   III-vii-15: He who inhabits all beings, but is within it, whom no being
>   knows, whose body is all beings, and who controls all beings from
>   within, is the Internal Ruler, your own immortal self. This much with
>   reference to the beings. Now with reference to the body. 
>  
>   III-vii-16: He who inhabits the nose, but is within it, whom the nose
>   does not know, whose body is the nose, and who controls the nose
>   from within, is the Internal Ruler, your own immortal self. 
>  
>   III-vii-17: He who inhabits the organ of speech, but is within it, whom
>   the organ of speech does not know, whose body is the organ of
>   speech, and who controls the organ of speech from within, is the Internal Ruler, your own immortal self. 
>  
>   III-vii-18: He who inhabits the eye, but is within it, whom the eye does
>   not know, whose body is the eye, and who controls the eye from
>   within, is the Internal Ruler, your own immortal self. 
>  
>   III-vii-19: He who inhabits the ear, but is within it, whom the ear does
>   not know, whose body is the ear, and who controls the ear from within,
>   is the Internal Ruler, your own immortal self. 
>  
>   III-vii-20: He who inhabits the mind (Manas), but is within it, whom the
>   mind does not know, whose body is the mind, and who controls the
>   mind from within, is the Internal Ruler, your own immortal self. 
>  
>   III-vii-21: He who inhabits the skin, but is within it, whom the skin does
>   not know, whose body is the skin, and who controls the skin from
>   within, is the Internal Ruler, your own immortal self. 
>  
>   III-vii-22: He who inhabits the intellect, but is within it, whom the
>   intellect does not know, whose body is the intellect, and who controls
>   the intellect from within, is the Internal Ruler, your own immortal self. 
>  
>   III-vii-23: He who inhabits the organ of generation, but is within it,
>   whom the organ of generation does not know, whose body is the organ
>   of generation, and who controls the organ of generation from within, is
>   the Internal Ruler, your own immortal self. He is never seen, but is the
>   Witness; He is never heard, but is the Hearer; He is never thought, but
>   is the Thinker; He is never known, but is the Knower. There is no other
>   witness but Him, no other hearer but Him, no other thinker but Him, no
>   other knower but Him. He is the Internal Ruler, your own immortal self.
>   Everything else but Him is mortal.’ Thereupon Uddalaka, the son of
>   Aruna, kept silent.

**Brief about the topics on which the debate took place -**

After brief Question Answer session between Gargi and Shree Yajnavalkya Rushi , Shree Uddalaka Aruni , Yajnavalkya's own teacher came forward to question him.
Uddalaka Aruni begins by asking Yajnavalkya about the **Inner controller (Anteryamin ,अंतरयामी )**.He made it quite clear to Yajnavalkya that he knows the answer to his 
question.**Thereupon Yajnavalkya gives a grand speech about Atman as the inner controller** , and Uddalka Aruni eventually  is silent.

Comment: How are we to interpret Yajnavalkya's answers to Gargi? They do not make sense.

Comment: @Surya haha... I do not have so much idea regarding this... I think we should look Adi Shankara Bhasya to understand this...